# Need validation with comma separated email address

Tags: magento-1.9, email, validation

i have used `System > Configuration > email field`

i need to comma-separated validation.

we can validate single email with the help of `validate-email` but i need to use in comma separated fields.

[image]

any solution for system configuration comma-separated email validation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add custom validation class like below in your `js` file

```
Validation.add('validate-comma-separated-emails', 'Please enter a valid email address.', function(emaillist) {
    emaillist = emaillist.trim();
    if(emaillist.charAt(0) == ',' || emaillist.charAt(emaillist.length - 1) == ','){ return false; }
    var emails = emaillist.split(',');
    var invalidEmails = [];
    for (i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) { 
    var v = emails[i].trim();
        if(!Validation.get('validate-email').test(v)) {
            invalidEmails.push(v);
        }
    }
    if(invalidEmails.length){ return false; }
    return true;
});
```

Now use `validate-comma-separated-emails` in your text field.
Tested with magento admin panel,
Output:
[image]

Comment: thanks for your quick response, but one suggestion i need to check should not enter first character as comma or last character as comma.

Comment: @denish , updated code. please check.

Comment: thanks for your help, i will accept your answer. just need one small help. if i will add space in last this is not work for last or first character comma validation.

Comment: @denishvachhani, You just have to trim the email lists. updated code. please check.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create own validation via js.

https://blog.kyp.fr/how-to-validate-magento-configuration-values-format/

Anyway I found some solutions :) :
[Using ajax validation for system configuration fields](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75342/using-ajax-validation-for-system-configuration-fields)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664396/how-to-validate-admin-config-options-for-magento-module

Comment: thanks for help, but i need multiple email validation with comma separated. i have seen your links which only gives single email validation which not appropriate in my questions. Thanks again for your reply and valuable time.